# Rescaling and reorienting Matrix Plot axes

Tags: plotting, matrix

I have implemented a numeric Laplace Solver in C++ and am trying to graphically represent the validity of my method. I have outputted the grid from C++ and imported it into *Mathematica* to get the following `MatrixPlot`:

[image: Matrix Plot]

And I wish to compare this directly to:

[image: Density Plot]

However; I am not sure how I can rearrange the axes. I wish for the `MatrixPlot` axes to be `{0.0,0.2,0.4,0.8,1.0}` like the contour plot (however, I cannot just use `FrameTick` as I wish to do larger matrices ($20\times 20$, $100\times 100$ and $1000\times 1000$, where it would be impractical to write each tick out by hand), and I also wish for the plot to be reoriented so it has the same orientation as the contour plot. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Karsten7. But then Mathematica interpolates over the points for me (which I don't want) and it still has axes going up to 7 instead of 1?

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you, that's useful; but how do I rescale the axes now?

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you so much, you've saved me a lot of time!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some data

```
m = Table[i*j, {i, 7}, {j, 7}];
```

Its

```
MatrixPlot[m]
```

> [image: matrix]

and a `ListDensityPlot` of the same data, without interpolation and rescaled axes:

```
ListDensityPlot[m, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

> [image: density]